# How to hide HTTP error 400 Ngrx + Firebase

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I want to hide this HTTP error when I sign in with incorrect credentials
Here is my effect and can I handle an error message by myself ?

```
@Effect()
   authSignin = this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN),
     tap(() => console.log("signin effect")),
     map((action: AuthActions.TrySignup) => {
       return action.payload;
     }),
 switchMap((authData: { username: string; password: string }) => {
  return from(
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(authData.username, authData.password)
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return from(firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken());
    }),
    mergeMap((token: string) => {
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      return [
        {
          type: AuthActions.SIGNIN
        },
        {
          type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
          payload: token
        }
      ];
    }),
    catchError(error =>
      Observable.of(new AuthActions.AuthError(error.message))
    )
  );
}),
catchError(error => Observable.of(new AuthActions.AuthError(error.message)))
  );
```

[image: Console display an error]
Console display an error

Comment: Open Network tab of dev tools and check response

Comment: Somewhere in your application you not catch the error that's why it show in the console.